# Is there a way to build go binary with C file e.g pdftotext from popper-utils?

Tags: c, go, pdftotext

My goal is to use `pdftotext` without the need to install `$ sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`.

The code:

```
   package main

   import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
   )

   func main() {
    body, err := exec.Command("pdftotext", "-layout", "-q", "-nopgbrk", "-enc", "UTF-8", "-eol", "unix", "/Volumes/T7Touch/Learn/e-statement-to-t-account/5725299769Jul2022.pdf", "-").Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
   }
```

What I've tried:

1. I use `pdftotext` which require installation and only available (without package manager like Homebrew) for linux by doing `$ sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`.

The problem:

1. If I run this go binary in my Mac, it won't work because I have not installed `poppler-utils`. I am only able to use this on `Visual Studio Code's dev container`.

Comment: Running your go-produced executable from a docker with installed poppler-utils seems the most reasonable. `pdftotext` has a bunch of dependencies that is unclear how to satisfy in general case. Pack all the stuff into a docker and don't worry ))

Comment: @PakUula I came to this conclusion after 3 days of failure, docker it is. I tried `pdfcpu.io, but I am not sure how to build application on top pdfcpu.io`, `ledongthuc/pdf, but the result is unreadable`, `trying to build PDF reader from a RFC docs, but it consisted of 700 pages, it is overkill`.